# How can I solve <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I create a association between two table 'Project' and 'Price'. In their respective model I wrote

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :name, :tagline,  presence: true
 has_many :prices
end
```

..and

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to  :project, :foreign_key => 'project_id'
end
```

But when I check in rails console, example

```
=> project = Project.last
=> project.prices
```

It is showing following error

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

..and

```
=>project.prices.count
=>0
```

Is anything missing?? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not an error, this is object which has been returned. Older ruby version returned the very same object, however it was delegating almost every method to the inner array (including inspect), so if you are doing some old tutorial it might tell you to expect `[]` to be returned. The behaviour you got is correct for newer versions (rails 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a error. According to Rails dicumentation it is

> "...middlemen between the object that holds the association, known as the @owner, and the actual associated object, known as the @target..."

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now I understand it very well. So, How can I get rid of this string ?

Comment: Try to create Price object: project.prices.build